# In Python, how do you find functions that (1) call a specific function and (2) have a certain decorator?

Tags: python

For example, if you have a file `code.py`:

```
def functionA():
    # does something

@some_decorator
def functionB():
    functionA()

@some_decorator
def functionC():
    functionD()

def functionD():
    functionA()
```

How can you write function `find_callers_with_decorator`, such that when you call `find_callers_with_decorator(code.py, 'some_decorator')`, it returns `['functionB', 'functionC']`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ast` module:

```
import ast

def find_callers_with_decorator(filename, decorator):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:
        module = ast.parse(handle.read())

    for node in module.body:
        if not isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
            continue

        if decorator in (d.id for d in node.decorator_list):
            yield node.name
```

Comment: @user1449565: That's not very specific. It works for your example code. Can you provide your actual code?

Comment: Exact same code and got error:
`AttributeError: 'Attribute' object has no attribute 'id'`. I have Python 2.7.2. Could you paste your output here?

Comment: @user1449565: Your code doesn't compile, it has a syntax error (your `functionA` has no body). I added `pass` in the function body so it compiled.

Comment: I did add a pass in `functinoA` and if you look at the error I pasted you'll see it's related to `d.id`. Can you paste your output/python version?

Comment: @user1449565: Python 2.7.9 and 3.4.3. `list(find_callers_with_decorator('code.py', 'some_decorator')) == ['functionB', 'functionC']`.